# How to start testcontainers with specific docker image?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I have a `junit` test, making use of `testcontainers-1.15.1`. How can I start an explicit image? Because:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ContainerTest {
   private final JdbcDatabaseContainer DB = new MariaDBContainer("mariadb:10.5.8");
  
   static {
       DB.start();
   }
   
   @Test
   public void test() { 

   } 
}
```

Result: the default `10.3.6` container is started.

```
[][] 2021-02-04 14:32:50,741 INFO ?.3.6]: Creating container for image: mariadb:10.3.6
[][] 2021-02-04 14:32:51,597 INFO ?.3.6]: Container mariadb:10.3.6 is starting: d9ccf77f4b9165ccd1690ee5cb8437f43e7d853dfe5121d468a391d67eccef7d
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mariadb:///test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

Comment: which version of Testcontainers are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might due to an inconsistent behavior of the constructors of the different Testcontainers modules in the past. It was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/commit/c3f53b3a63e6b0bc800a7f0fbce91ce95a8986b3#diff-c93975df49b24c6c448c444b5fbb33d915655cee58976d290b72afe3bd8e124a) and should be available since Testcontainers 1.15.0.

Not sure if your sample was pseudo test code, but the following example is a valid copy-pastable example:

```
public class MariaDbContainerTest {

  private static final JdbcDatabaseContainer DB = new MariaDBContainer("mariadb:10.5.8");

  static {
    DB.start();
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {

  }
}
```

I've tested it for both Testcontainers 1.15.0 and 1.15.1 and *it works on my machine*.

**UPDATE**: I've not seen that you also specify the JDBC support of Testcontainers inside your `application.properties` file in addition to your manual container definition as part of your test.

Pick either the JDBC support **OR** the manual container definition and your problem should be resolved.

When using the JDBC support you can also specify the version of your database: `jdbc:tc:mariadb:10.5.8:///test`

Comment: Strange, I'm also on 1.15.1. Could this be somehow any caching issue? Is there a cache for testcontainers explicit?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But you can still try to remove the relevant Docker images first

Comment: Where would I have to remove it?

Comment: Inside a shell with the following command `docker rmi <nameOfTheImage>`. With `docker images` you get an overview of all your downloaded images.

Comment: I did so, and first get the log `Container mariadb:10.5.8 started in...`, but then directly after: `Container mariadb:10.3.6 is starting`....

Comment: I created an issue for this: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3779

Comment: I overlooked your `application.properties` JDBC container definition, sorry. I've updated my answer

Comment: Okay, but if setting the version in application.properties, I would then have to repeat the version also in the `MariaDBContainer` constructor (because empty constructor is `@Deprecated`). Preferably I would want to mention the mariadb version only once...

Comment: you don't need any `MariaDBContainer` definition anymore in your test. Testcontainers will start & stop the database for you based on this _magic_ JDBC URL. Take a look at the last setup of this [article](https://rieckpil.de/test-your-spring-boot-jpa-persistence-layer-with-datajpatest/).

Comment: Ok my main advantage of starting the container myself in the past from `static` context was that I could reuse the testcontainer between test runs. But this will be gone if I omit the constructor creation. While there is a `.testcontainers` file that could hold a property to reuse, the bad is that it has to be placed into the home directory. Is there any way to reuse the container simply from classpath definitions, when using the `magic jdbc url`approach?

Comment: That's a completely different question - I recommend creating a new question on SO as I assume your original problem is now solved.

Comment: Yes, ok. I also just learned that forcing reuse from classpath only is not possible unfortunately.